# GAE ReferenceProperty Error from option value

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I'm trying to add a new Goal via POST using my select option populated by the Referenced Category.  The dropdown populates correctly, but the key I'm getting from the value returned is causing a ReferenceProperty Error.

models.py:

```
class Categories(db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
  amount = db.FloatProperty(required=True)

class Goals(db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
  amount = db.FloatProperty(required=True)
  category = db.ReferenceProperty(Categories)
```

add_goal.html:

```
select type="select" name="category" id="id_cat"  
{% for c in cats %}
option value='{{c.name}}'  {{ c.name }}  /option
{% endfor %}
/select>
```

CORRECTED VERSION:
    {% for c in cats %}
         {{ c.name }} 
        {% endfor %}

views.py:

```
def post(self):
    cat_key = db.Key.from_path('Categories', self.request.get('category'))
    logging.info('cat_key= '+ str(cat_key))

    g = Goals(name=self.request.get('name'),
                category=cat_key,
                 amount=float(self.request.get('amount')))
    g.put()
    return webapp2.redirect('/view_goals')
```

CORRECTED VERSION:
        def post(self):
        cat_key = db.Key.from_path('Categories', int(self.request.get('category')))

```
    g = Goals(name=self.request.get('name'),
                category=cat_key,
                 amount=float(self.request.get('amount')))
    g.put()
```

Comment: Figured out a solution for anyone else wondering how to do this:

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer below, and accept it after 2 days; that will mark the question as properly solved.